# Background worker in windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have the following constellation:

MainForm.cs -> Including all my Form Elements

Program.cs -> includes the main part, which is a xmlreader/writer to alter xml attributes in xml files that can be as large as 4gb

So this little app works but of course the UI gets unresponsive and freezes which I want to avoid, I also hope to reduce the duration of this process on the way

I start the call of my xmlread/write method from a BtnClick event:

```
    void BtnApplyChangesClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Program p = Program.Instance;
        pbApplyChanges.Minimum = 0;
        pbApplyChanges.Step = 1;

        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        foreach(DataGridViewRow cr in dataGridView2.Rows)
        {
            pbApplyChanges.Maximum = dataGridView2.Rows.Count;
            p.changeElements(cr.Cells["Filename"].Value.ToString(), txtTenant.Text, txtDate.Text, txtEvtId2.Text);
            pbApplyChanges.PerformStep();
        }
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Arrow;
        MessageBox.Show("Job done");
    }
```

In the call I use my singleton instance of Program.cs and my main Method there (changeElements) uses 4 String params, that are all taken from information in the Form! (I suppose this is kinda bad practice but it worked so far...)

When I tried to replace this method call with a backgroundWorker (itself made the method call then) I failed as the method call wasn't even made... I found out that UI elements can't be accessed from the BW thread, so I suppose this is also the reason for my method call not working?!

So how can I get this constellation to work? Do I have to pass all 4 string Params AND the class instance (of Program.cs) to the background worker? Is BW even the best tool for the job?

Comment: no, you can make class and params global. (Ofcourse if you dont need multithread)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general the BackgroundWorker shouldn't access any UI-Elements. It's an old advice in Winforms that accessing UI-Elements should just happen from the UI-Thread.

You can use the Background-Worker like this:

```
private void Main(string[] args)
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += Bw_DoWork;
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += Bw_RunWorkerCompleted;

    //Parameter you need to work in Background-Thread for example your strings
    string[] param = new[] {"Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text4"};

    //Start work
    bw.RunWorkerAsync(param);
}

//Do your Background-Work
private void Bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string[] param = e.Argument as string[];

    //Process your long running  task

    e.Result = null; //Set your Result of the long running task
}

//Taking your results
private void Bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //Apply your Results to your GUI-Elements
    myTextBox1.Text = e.Result.ToString();
}
```

Background-Worker is some old school stuff by the way, so if you like to learn something new take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) and inform yourself about the TPL. This gives you a better handling of asynchronous.

In fact I think it's not really good to store 4gb data in a XML-File. Do you think about a Database? Or split the XML-File in many XML-Files? So you would be able to read data in chunks.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi sebi, this is helpful but my main problem persists, I iterate through rows of my datagrid (which represent the xml files in the directory usually 19-21 files) Afaiu the foreach should be made in the backgroundworkerDoWork but the datagrid is not accessible from there... so do I have to also pass the datagrid object to backgroundworker?

Comment: @KlausKerner How do you fill your DataGrid? You should have a DataSource for example a DataTable. Pass this as argument to your BackgroundWorker. No GUI-Elements.

Comment: oh sure ocourse you're right, it's a DataTable that can be used, completely forgot about it THX

Answer (score 1):

I don't use background worker for this. I use normal threads instead. Try this code:

```
public void ButtonDoWork_Click(eventArgs......) {
    DoWorkThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork)); // Setup thread
    DoWorkThread.isBackground = true; // Its background so, we need to set background flag
    DoWorkThread.Start(); // Start the thread
}

private Thread DoWorkThread: // our Thread object
private void DoWork() { // This void contains action that will be performed by thread
    //TODO: Background processing. To update UI from another thread use Control.Invoke(...)
}
```

Please note, I don't tested this code - I write it from my memory and it's late so it can not work.

You can also read about Threads at MSDN :)

Comment: thx for the input, so far the bgworker did work finally I also like that it is easy to set up with progressbar so it makes kinda sense in my little app... but I will definitely experiment with multiple threads because I feel like the performance could be a lot better, especially parallel execution would make lots of sense as I have to handle about 20 xml files at once ranging from 5-1500 mb ;) -> this is not my decision btw I have to work with these xmls as lame as it may be...